# org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filterdispatcher not allowing other filters in the chain to get triggered?

Tags: struts2

I am using struts 2. In my `web.xml` I am having the following configuration,

```
    <filter>
        <description>filter for application</description>
        <display-name>AppBasicFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>AppBasicFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myapp.AppBasicFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AppBasicFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

For this configuration, I am getting my action classes triggerd properly. But Neither before nor after action class execution, my `AppBasicFilter` is not getting triggerd.

I tried to decompile and see the struts 2 FilterDispatcher coding, I saw that if mapping is present, its not doing `FilterChain.doFilter()` in it.

This problem is because of that. can someone please help me?

Comment: What are you using the filter for, exactly?  Is it something that you could instead use an interceptor for?  Also, the filter you are using has been deprecated since 2.1.3, instead you should use the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that its a problem with FilterDispatcher. So I have to work with StritsPrepareAndExecuteFilter which is available in struts 2.1 or greater. But unfortunately my project was using struts 2.0. So I migrated to struts 2.1 and made it work.